# Load more data after scrolling tableview (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, twitter

i'm making a test app for twitter using this tutorial http://tutorials.veasoftware.com/2013/09/20/twitter-api-version-1-1-user-timeline-in-ios-7/
So how can load more data from user_timeline after scrolling tableview? I load 10 tweets from user_timeline.json (10 last tweets) on viewDidLoad. How can i load 10 more tweets from last date? DO i need to check date of my last tweet and make a new request? Or something different? Can anybody show the example?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a pull-to-load UI. I suggest you do a Google search on "UITableView pull to load". I think there are sample projects on github/other sites that show how to do this.